# In Python, what's the purpose of giving an alias with the same name as the imported lib?

Tags: python, import, python-import

When I was reading the source code of `aiohttp`, I found the code below:
[click here for code](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/f922c1985d74509366f68152ddd940f121fc40e5/aiohttp/web.py#L25)

```
from .web_exceptions import (
    HTTPAccepted as HTTPAccepted,
    HTTPBadGateway as HTTPBadGateway,
    HTTPBadRequest as HTTPBadRequest,
    HTTPClientError as HTTPClientError,
    HTTPConflict as HTTPConflict,
    HTTPCreated as HTTPCreated,
    HTTPError as HTTPError,
...
)
```

I don't understand why we need a `import A as A` here.
Are there any benefits?

Comment: The point of doing this is to use a shorter name. The code you've shown is pointless. Perhaps it was written by a code generation tool; maybe it's intended that you go in and edit the aliases to what you prefer.

Comment: @kindall This is part of a what looks like a pretty professionally writtten 3rd party library, aiohttp. It uses that pattern a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the Git blame to the [original commit](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/commit/4a2fba9ff13ef90ca751c5d1055ad0f87b856268), and following that to the [pull request](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/pull/3872) and [associated issue](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/3868), shows that this was to make mypy happy. `mypy --strict` didn't like the no-`as` form for re-exported imports.